# couchdb, use middleware or not? Which for simple restful API, with express4 nodejs

Tags: javascript, express, couchdb, node-modules, couchdb-nano

I don't find a lot of examples about couchdb with nodejs and express4.

I've seen there are on npm:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-couchdb
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/nano

they are compatible with couchdb 2?

or there is a way to work without middleware? in this case it's better to work without middleware to understand better how works couchdb? I'd like to read some examples about that.

Comment: The most common modules used are probably PouchDB, nano and node-couchdb.  Working without any library would indeed, help you understand more the HTTP API of CouchDB. Therefore, you'll waste a lot of time creating that is already existing.

Comment: thanks, you woud suggest me try PouchDB, and with that i have all i need? i've read it's to work offline in browser too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the documentation of PouchDB is absolutely awesome. You have a bigger community(in my opinion) around PouchDB and it's constantly evolving. If it's not fully compatible with CouchDB 2.0, it will be very soon. They are also already implementing the Mango Query.

Nano is very minimalist compared to PouchDB.Everything depends on your needs. Also, PouchDB offers you the possibility to use Promises which make it easier to write clean code compared to nano callbacks.

Nano and PouchDB are good libraries and I highly suggest that you start using one of those libraries. Unless you want to build something very different from those, building your own library would be a waste of time. You might want to focus more on the core of your project than building an library to access CouchDB's API.